# How to calculate tilt angle when 2 edges are known?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have placed a depth camera on the ceiling which has a focal view of 60-degree vertically; the camera is placed tilt as it covers a larger area of a floor. what is the angle between the camera lance vertical FOV and a line perpendicular to the floor? The rest is explained in the image.

[Explaination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMVfV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would know the height of the camera to the floor, it would have been a lot easier. But without it, it is possible. Suppose we call the perpendicular length between the floor and the camera $C$, the FOV angle $\beta$ (in this case 30 degrees) and the unknown angle $\alpha$:
$$(1) \quad A\text{cos}(\beta+\alpha) = C$$
$$(2) \quad B\text{cos}(\alpha) = C$$
Next split the angles in equation (1):
$$A\text{cos}(\beta)\text{cos}(\alpha)-A\text{sin}(\beta)\text{sin}(\alpha) = C$$
Divide this equation by equation (2):
$$\text{cos}(\beta)\frac{A}{B} - \text{sin}(\beta)\frac{A}{B}\frac{\text{sin}(\alpha)}{\text{cos}(\alpha)} = 1$$
$$\text{cos}(\beta)\frac{A}{B} - 1 = \text{sin}(\beta)\frac{A}{B}\text{tan}(\alpha)$$
and isolate $\alpha$:
$$\frac{\text{cos}(\beta)}{\text{sin}(\beta)} - \frac{B}{A\text{sin}(\beta)} = \text{tan}(\alpha)$$
$$\alpha = \text{arctan}\left(\frac{\text{cos}(\beta)}{\text{sin}(\beta)} - \frac{B}{A\text{sin}(\beta)}\right)$$

If I made a mistake anywhere, please tell me.